# Earth ground to dsub9 shell

Tags: ground, earth

I have an enclosure containing an earth ground line. It has a brass earth ground bus that is connected to:

- the input earth pin of a 120V single-phase mains IEC320-C14 connector
- the output earth pin of a 120V single-phase NEMA 5-15R connector
- earth terminal for a self-contained SMPS with a metal case

The enclosure is ABS, so I haven't bothered to ground it.

I'm considering adding another ground connection from the bus to an [L717SDE09P](https://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/amphenol-commercial-products/L717SDE09P/L717SDE09P-ND/1930961) DSUB9 connector. The connector shell is tin-plated steel. It has "grounding indents" which I assume are the indents on the exterior (pin) side of the shell.

Currently I'm considering running a copper stranded wire from the earth bus to something in the [ring crimp category](https://www.digikey.ca/products/en/connectors-interconnects/terminals-ring-connectors/394). The ring would sit on the interior of the enclosure between a washer and a nut on one of the DB9 shell's jack screws. **Is this a viable approach?** Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a good idea to ground DSUB connector shells. See here for a first hand account of what might happen if they are not: [What is the "ground strap" on a D-SUB connector for?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/23041/what-is-the-ground-strap-on-a-d-sub-connector-for/23043#23043)

A ring crimp connector on the jack screws that connects to a wire going to the ground bus should work just fine. In fact, I did almost the exact same thing on one of my projects and have had no problems.